# Method for saving checkbox in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is there anyway to save checkbox state after closing application?
For dbgrid i'm using SaveToFile method, does something similar exists for checkbox?

Comment: `TIniFile.WriteBool`?

Comment: Save state to a file, or to the registry if targeting windows only.

Comment: I would suggest creating a table with column of `bit` type where you are going to store values `True` for checked and `False` for unchecked. Then you need to connect checkbox with `TEdit` component somehow (of example `if TEdit.Text = 'True' then checkbox.state := checked`). You would also need a `TQuery` component to open itself on form create and select values from bit column and insert it to te `TEdit` field connected to the checkbox.

Comment: The Jedi Visual Component Library (JVCL) contains a TFormStorage component that allows saving any published property of any component on a form to an INI file or the registry.

Comment: , You can read and set the state of a checkbox in code, so you can save and restore its state in any way you like - others have suggested some ways.  However, if you are asking about a TDBCheckBox, you would do better simply to save/restore the value of the DB field associated with the checkbox.